# How to find old (possibly unmaintained) npm dependendencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I know that `npm outdated` exists, which lists out-of-date dependencies, but only in case there was new a version published.

But in some cases (e.g. abandoned project) there might **be no new version published** and package might be still considered **out of date**.

Is there way to find dependencies which were unchanged (no new version) in a longer time - specifically, find all packages didn't publish new version in 2 years?

Reasoning behind is that there is high risk that very old dependencies might be already out of date and not fully compatible with latest Node.js/TypeScript or other linked dependencies. Those dependencies would still need manual review, but having this list would be helpful.

*Searching for solution compatible primarily with `npm` package manager. But would be nice if it can work also with `yarn`.*

Comment: How would you automatically differentiate between "out of date" and "it was already done in 2013, it has had no updates because it doesn't _need_ updates, it does exactly what it should do and nothing more, and has done so for a decade now"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is good question. I can imagine setting parameter like I want to see all dependencies which were not updated in like 2 years. Then I can review those manually.

Answer (score 1):

A funny hack could be to check the `last-modified` header of the resolved URL of each dependency.

Try this

```bash
for dep in $(npm ls --json | jq -r '.dependencies | .[].resolved'); do
  when="$(curl -sI $dep | grep -i last-modified: | sed 's/[^:]*..//' | tr -d '\r')";
  echo "$(date --date="$when" -I): $dep"
done
```

It may print something like

```
2022-08-04: https://registry.npmjs.org/@testing-library/jest-dom/-/jest-dom-5.16.5.tgz
2022-09-04: https://registry.npmjs.org/@testing-library/react/-/react-13.4.0.tgz
2021-10-18: https://registry.npmjs.org/@testing-library/user-event/-/user-event-13.5.0.tgz
2022-06-14: https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dom/-/react-dom-18.2.0.tgz
2022-11-01: https://registry.npmjs.org/react-router-dom/-/react-router-dom-6.4.3.tgz
2022-04-12: https://registry.npmjs.org/react-scripts/-/react-scripts-5.0.1.tgz
2022-06-14: https://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-18.2.0.tgz
2022-01-21: https://registry.npmjs.org/web-vitals/-/web-vitals-2.1.4.tgz
```

If you're also interested in dependencies of your dependencies, you could swap the `npm ls --json` for `cat package-lock.json` in the above example.

Comment: If you need only the values of an object, just [use `.[]`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#array-object-value-iterator) not `to_entries`. So `'.dependencies.[].resolved'` should suffice

Comment: This seems like pretty interesting approach. Just would be great to sort it by date..

Comment: Also are you aware if it's possible to list dependencies like that using `yarn` ? (Looks like `resolved` field is missing on yarn setup projects)

Comment: `yarn.lock` has that field too, but it's a custom format that needs its own parsing (800 loc), so either use it `@yarnpkg/lockfile` or otherwise use some sketchy grepping like `grep resolved yarn.lock | grep -o 'http[^"]*'`

Comment: Note this is all a terrible hack but it does seem to work. 

You may want to look into ways to paralellizing all the curl calls if there are 100s or 1000s of pkgs. Maybe with gnu parallel